# What is the difference between "swarm master" and "swarm manager"?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I am using the latest docker for mac (17.09.0-ce), when I run `docker-machine create --help` it says
...

```
--swarm-master  Configure Machine to be a Swarm master
```

But the document [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#understanding-swarm-clusters) said "run docker swarm init to enable swarm mode and make your current machine a swarm manager"

So what is the difference between swarm master and swarm manager?

------ update -------

I found this so post explained it all, [Need for service discovery for docker engine swarm mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786414/need-for-service-discovery-for-docker-engine-swarm-mode)

Comment: the swarm can contain many managers, only one of them is the leader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different implementations of Swarm, with slightly different terminology.

The `docker-machine` command is configuring the classic container-based Swarm. You can find it on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/swarm/). This version of swarm is more like a reverse proxy to the various docker engines.

The `docker swarm init` command enables [Swarm Mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) that is now included with the docker engine. Swarm Mode is closer in features to Kubernetes and provides orchestration. You will most likely want Swarm Mode, classic Swarm is being preserved for historical reasons and special use cases.